Unit test with TestBed : problem with the interpretation of "params" property of the ActivatedRoute snapshot
I am currently developping a unit test component in Cypress using TestBed for a component which needs to provide an ActivatedRoute with a parameter in the snapshot.
I precise that this parameter is used by the component to determine a property of the component (there's a line like "this.componentParameter = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params['myParameter']") which is used by the component to make a get request to the API when it is loaded.
In function of the way I provide the ActivatedRoute, either the component parameter is defined but the component is not displayed by Cypress, or the component is displayed but the component parameter is undefined.
I tried like this :
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    imports: [ ...],
    declarations: [...],
    providers: [
        { provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: {
            snapshot: {
                params: of({
                    myParameter: 1
                }),
                data: {
                    ...
                }
            }
            }
        }
}).compileComponents();

fixture = TestBed.createComponent(myComponent); 
component = fixture.componentInstance;
fixture.detectChanges();

In this case the component is displayed but the component property is undefined.
And in this other case the component property is defined but the component is not displayed :
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    imports: [ ...],
    declarations: [...],
    providers: [
        { provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: {
            snapshot: {
                params: {
                    myParameter: 1
                },
                data: {
                    ...
                }
            }
            }
        }
}).compileComponents();

fixture = TestBed.createComponent(myComponent); 
component = fixture.componentInstance;
fixture.detectChanges();


Could you try mocking a subscribe event, by providing a arrow function with an input argument as callback and executing the callback with the param value!
I am assuming you are using a simple subscribe with a callback inside, if your subscribe method is complex, the mock object needs to be adjusted accordingly!
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    imports: [ ...],
    declarations: [...],
    providers: [
        { provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: {
            snapshot: {
                params: {
                    subscribe: (callback) => {
                        callback({
                            myParameter: 1,
                        })
                    }),
                },
                data: {
                    ...
                }
            }
            }
        }
}).compileComponents();


Thank you for your help, but it doesn't work for me :  the component is displayed, but the component property is undefined
